# Show $\frac{d}{dx}$ is bounded on $C^k[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I would like to show that differentiation given by $\frac{d}{dx}:C^{k+1}[a,b]\to C^k[a,b]$ is a bounded/continuous linear transformation. I have a theorem stating that boundedness, continuous at one point, and uniformly continuous are equivalent on a normed linear space, so I only need to prove one of these.

First, I think I would like to show that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is a linear transformation, and then after show that it is bounded/continuous? That$\frac{d}{dx}$ is a linear transformation seems to me immediately clear by properties of derivatives and continuous functions, so all I need to show is that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is bounded/continuous.

I would appreciate a hint as to which of these I should try to prove, and if it is boundedness, what a reasonably bound might be, and if it is continuity, then what definition of continuity I should consider.

Thank you!

Edit: To clarify, $C^k[a,b]$ is the collection of $k$-differentiable continuous functions on the interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Edit 2: Here is the definition of boundedness that I am working with. A linear transformation $T:V\to W$ where $V$ and $W$ are normed vector spaces is bounded if there exists a $C\geq 0$ such that $||T_v||_W\leq C||v||_V$ for all $v\in V$.

I was thinking maybe $C$ would relate somehow to an exponent of $k+1$ power, because when we take the derivative this becomes a scalar multiple, but there is no guarantee that this is the largest exponent, since everything in $C^{k+1}$ has to be at Least $k+1$-differentiable?

Comment: Generally $C^k$ is as you described it, with the additional assumption that the final derivative is also continuous. Is this not the case here? If it is you're done.

Comment: @AlexR. I do not believe that I have this additional assumption

Comment: With regards to continuity, since $f \in C^k$ is $k$-differentiable, then $f' \in C^{k-1}$ is $k-1$ differentiable. But recall the differentiable functions are in fact continuous (use fact $f'(x) - f'(a) = [ f'(x)-f'(a) ]/ (x-a) \cdot (x-a)$ and take $x \to a$

Comment: @welshman500 Thank you for the hint, but I'm not really sure what you are getting at. I understand that $f$ and $f'$ should be continuous but I don't see how this equation helps prove continuity of the derivative. I'm not sure what the limit should be

Comment: If $x \to a$, then $(f'(x) -f'(a))/(x-a) \to f''(a)$ which is well-defined meaning that it's product with $\lim (x-a) = 0$ is ok. Thus $\lim f'(x) - f'(a)  =0$ as $x \to a$ and so $f'$ has to be continuous. This works for $k\ge 1$ which I think is the case you are working in.

Comment: If you want to prove $d/dx$ is bounded, you need some norm on $C^{k+1}$ and $C^k$.  What norms are you using?

Comment: @welshman500 Thank you, I think this makes sense to me- let me see if I can work through the rest of the problem.

Comment: @Strants both $C^{k+1}$ and $C^k$ here are equipped with the maximum norm, so $||f||=\max_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)|$

Comment: @welshman500 After thinking this through more, I believe that I should be able to prove continuity via a delta-epsilon proof and the maximum norm. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: @MathStudent1324 Are you sure that's the right norm for the spaces?  $d/dx$ is *not* a continuous map for these norms.

Answer (score 0):

The norm on $C^k$ is usually given as
$$
         \|f\|_{C^k} = \|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}+\cdots+\|f^{(k)}\|_{\infty}.
$$
At least it is equivalent to this norm. Therefore,
$$
     \|f'\|_{C^k} = \|f'\|_{\infty}+\|f''\|_{\infty}+\cdots\|f^{(k+1)}\|_{\infty} 
   \le \|f\|_{C^{k+1}}.
$$
So $Lf=f'$ is continuous from $C^{k+1}$ to $C^{k}$.